# header rule margin with boxes

Tags: spacing, header-footer, boxes, rules

I'm creating a document with a box in the header and an other one in the footer.

But I would like to have the same space between the bottom of the top box and header rule and between the top of the bottom box and the footer rule.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%\usepackage[top=2.25cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.25cm, right=2.25cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{layout}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{1cm}          % 1
%\setlength{\voffset}{1cm}          % 2
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}  % 3 
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm}    
%\setlength{\topmargin}{.cm}        % 4
%\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}      % 5 
%\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}         % 6 
%\setlength{\textheight}{1cm}       % 7 
%\setlength{\textwidth}{1cm}        % 8
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}     % 9
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1cm}   % 10 
%\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}       % 11 
%\setlength{\marginparpush}{1cm}    % 12
\setlength{\parindent}{57pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancyhf{}

\lhead[\textcolor{black}{A}]{\textcolor{gray}{B}}
\chead{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{C}}}               
\rhead[\textcolor{black}{D}]{\textcolor{gray}{E}}       
\lfoot[\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage}]{\textcolor{gray}{F}}    
\cfoot{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{G}}}                               
\rfoot[\textcolor{black}{\today}]{\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage / }}       

\fancyhfoffset{50pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
    \color{red}\hrule \headwidth \headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{\headrulewidth}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{{%
     \color{blue}\vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
\hrule \headwidth \footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}

\pagestyle{fancy}       

\begin{document}        
\lipsum \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

I tried to change all the values in the `layout` options but none of them change the space between the C `fbox` and the header rule or between the G `fbox` and the footer rule. I found nothing on the Internet about this kind of settings.

Someone can help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding a vertical space `vspace` to the ruler. I think this can be useful, thus here is the code:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancyhf{}

\lhead[\textcolor{black}{A}]{\textcolor{gray}{B}}
\chead{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{C}}}               
\rhead[\textcolor{black}{D}]{\textcolor{gray}{E}}       
\lfoot[\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage}]{\textcolor{gray}{F}}    
\cfoot{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{G}}}                               
\rfoot[\textcolor{black}{\today}]{\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage / }}       

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
  \vpace{3pt}  \color{red}\hrule \headwidth \headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\renewcommand{\footrule}{{%
 \color{blue}\vskip-\footruleskip-\vskip-\footrulewidth
  \hrule \headwidth \footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}

\pagestyle{fancy}       

\begin{document}        
\lipsum \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open up the `\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}` command in preamble you can achieve what you wanted to do

Comment: A full example would make this a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Full Code

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%\usepackage[top=2.25cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.25cm, right=2.25cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{layout}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{1cm}          % 1
%\setlength{\voffset}{1cm}          % 2
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5cm}  % 3 
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm}    
%\setlength{\topmargin}{.cm}        % 4
%\setlength{\headheight}{17pt}      % 5 
%\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}         % 6 
%\setlength{\textheight}{1cm}       % 7 
%\setlength{\textwidth}{1cm}        % 8
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}     % 9
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1cm}   % 10 
\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}       % 11 
%\setlength{\marginparpush}{1cm}    % 125
\setlength{\parindent}{57pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancyhf{}

\lhead[\textcolor{black}{A}]{\textcolor{gray}{B}}
\chead{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{C}}}               
\rhead[\textcolor{black}{D}]{\textcolor{gray}{E}}       
\lfoot[\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage}]{\textcolor{gray}{F}}    
\cfoot{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{G}}}                               
\rfoot[\textcolor{black}{\today}]{\textcolor{gray}{page \thepage / }}       

\fancyhfoffset{50pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{{%
    \color{red}\hrule \headwidth \headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{\headrulewidth}

\renewcommand{\footrule}{{%
     \color{blue}\vskip-\footruleskip-\vskip-\footrulewidth
\hrule \headwidth \footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}

\pagestyle{fancy}       

\begin{document}        
\lipsum \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your other answer and add the code there instead of posting a new one.

Comment: That is a good try but not really what I expected. Maybe I didn't make it clear. What I would like to change is the space between the red box created by the line `\chead{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{C}}` and the red line created by the line `\renewcommand{\headrule}{{    \color{red}\hrule \headwidth \headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}`

the command `\setlength{\footskip}{1.5cm}` allows to change the space between the main text (here `\lipsum`) and the footer, so this is not the same things.